# Characteristic function : in what is more useful than the density function?

Tags: probability

The principal thing I know with the characteristic function is : $X$ and $Y$ have the same law $\iff$ the characteristic function are the same. But if they have the same density function, they also have the same law, no ? So $X$ and $Y$ has the same law $\iff$ they have the same density function. Now, in what the characteristic function is more useful than the density to prove that two r.v. have the same law ? Since we first need to know that the density function before computing the characteristic function.

Comment: The characteristic function is used for much more than that. Wait tiil you see the proof of the Central Limit Theorem...

Comment: **Not all random variables have density functions!**  And there can be many ways to determine the characteristic function of a random variable, other than by doing an integral with respect to its density function (assuming it even has one).

Comment: @NateEldredge: How can you determine the characteristic function to a r.v. that has no density function since the characteristic function is the Fourier transform of the density function. Could you provide an example ?

Comment: @NewMath: The characteristic function is defined as $\phi(t) = E[e^{itX}]$.  So for instance, if $X$ has a Bernoulli(1/2) distribution (which is discrete and has no density), we have $\phi(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{it \cdot 0} + \frac{1}{2} e^{it \cdot 1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^{it}$.